# Page refresh after postback from UpdatePanel in Sharepoint 2013 (with auth check)

Tags: updatepanel, sharepoint-2013

Strange behavior appears when using Updatepanel on Apllication page or usercontrol in Sharepoint 2013.

In FF and Chrome postback leads to full page refresh after small idle between requests (around 30 seconds). Example: we have a page with button and label inside UpdatePanel. We open this page and click the button -> updatepanel refreshes its content without page reload. If we will wait more than 30 seconds and click the button again, page will reload.

In Firebug or Fiddler we can see follow:

1) POST-request from updatepanel to server

2) Response from server will contains

1|#||4|53|pageRedirect||/_login/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=
3) After there will be request to /_login/default.aspx and then redirect to  /_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=

4) And then it will be redirected to my initial page.

Users see only page reload.

But if we will wait a long time (around 20 minutes) there will be not page reload and updatepanel refreshes only their content.

This error happens in different environment in defferent domains. We use standart Claims based authentication and Minimal Download Strategy feature is disabled.

In IE this error occurs, but not so often.

I found that error disappears if Form Authentication is disabled in IIS web application (but in this case there are some problems in another pages in portal).

Can anyone help me with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio 2012 Designer Code Generator is really screwy for sharepoint.  Are you using Visual Studio 2012 by any chance?

If so I strongly recommend upgrading to Visual Studio 2013.  Visual Studio 2012 is the Windows Vista of IDE's.  Microsoft released 2013 really faster after 2012 to address all of it's issues.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, i use VS2012. Do you think this behavior of Updatepanel is related with VS2012? I think it is related with authentition proccess, but i will try VS2013.

Comment: It's not that the update panel doesn't work in visual studio 2012, it's that the designer generated code, what Visual Studio compiles when you put the update panel in markup, is buggy in vs2012.

Not saying it will solve your problem, just that vs2013 fixes a ton of bugs in vs2012.

Answer (score 0):

has nothing to do with visual studio, IMHO.
here is a thread about it:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/c33d4a46-87d6-4dbc-a24c-cb8e5f9eb1ea/page-refresh-after-postback-from-updatepanel-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

pointing to a hotfix:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2910945

which addresses this issue: "When you browse to a SharePoint 2013 page that contains an UpdatePanel control, the page may be refreshed randomly. Therefore, if you type something in a text field on the page, the text field may become empty."

FYI, I installed it and it didn't resolve my issue, but it might help you.

Yes, this is an authentication configuration issue - means your claims authentication is not set up correctly probably, so the authentication cookie is missing/not sent with our ajax request.

Please update back if this KB resolved it for you, I want to keep track of this issue.